# Fixed points of subtorus in Nakajima quiver variety (Lemma 3.2 in Nakajima's Quiver varieties and tensor products)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, quiver

I am having trouble understanding the proof of lemma 3.2 in Nakajima's paper "Quiver varieties and tensor products," [available on arxiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0103008.pdf). This is where he shows that the fixed components of a subtorus of the residual action on a quiver variety are themselves quiver varieties.

Fix a decomposition of dimension vector $w = w' + w''$, and the corresponding decomposition of framed spaces $W = W^1 \oplus W^2$. Define a one parameter subgroup $\lambda: \mathbb C^* \to G_W$ by
$$
\lambda(t) = \text{id}_{W^1} \oplus t \text{id}_{W^2} \in G_{W^1} \times G_{W^2} \subset G_W
$$

**Lemma 3.2**: *The fixed point set of $\lambda(\mathbb C^*)$ in $\mathfrak M(v, w)$ is isomorphic to $\sqcup_{v^1 + v^2 = v}\mathfrak M(v^1,w^1) \times \mathfrak M(v^2,w^2)$.*

**Proof**: $[B,i,j] \in \mathfrak M(v,w)$ is fixed by $\lambda(\mathbb C^*)$ iff there exists a one-parameter subgroup $\rho: \mathbb C^* \to G_V$ such that
$$
(\star) \quad \quad \lambda(t) * (B,i,j) = \rho(t)^{-1}(B,i,j)
$$
This is just unwinding the definitions of $\mathfrak M(v,w)$, but I am not certain what the action on either side of this equation is. I think Nakajima defines $*$ towards the top of page 13 where he says:

> Let $G_W = \Pi_{k \in I}GL(W_k)$. It acts naturally on **M**, $\mathfrak M$ and $\mathfrak M_0$. We define $\mathbb C^*$-actions on $\mathfrak M$ and $\mathfrak M_0$ by
> $$
> B_h \mapsto t^{m(h) + 1}B_h,\quad i \mapsto ti, \quad j \mapsto tj \quad (t \in \mathbb C^*)
> $$

For simplicity, let's take $m \equiv 0$.

> We denote this action by $(B,i,j) \mapsto g * (B,i,j)$ or $[B,i,j] \mapsto g*[B,i,j]$ for $g \in G_W \times \mathbb C^*$.

1. Here I believe B is the collection of morphisms $V \to V$, and $i$ is the collection $V \to W$ and $j$ is the collection $W \to V$. Concretely, what is this action? It seems to me that both $G_W$ and $\mathbb C^*$ want to act on the $i$ and $j$ maps. Nakajima writes "this action" but it looks to me like he just described two different ones.

> Let $V^1$ (resp. $V^2)$ be the eigenspace of $V$ with eigenvalue 1 (resp. $t$). Let $V'$ be the sum of other eigenspaces. The above equation implies that
> $$
> 1) B(V^1) \subset V^1, B(V^2) \subset V^2, B(V') \subset V'
> $$
> $$
> 2) i(W^1) \subset V^1, i(W^2) \subset V^2
> $$
> $$
> 3) j(V^1) \subset W^1, j(V^2) \subset W^2, j(V') = 0
> $$

2. The equation above is equation $(\star)$. Am I right that these are eigenspaces with respect to $\rho^{-1}(t)$? And how do I see this conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $m(h)=1$ for all $h$, there is a $\mathbb G_m$ action on $\mathfrak M$ given on
$$
E(V,W) = E(V,V)\oplus L(W,V)\oplus L(V,W),
$$
by $t.(B,i,j) = (tB,ti,tj)$. Since it commutes with the $G_V$ action, it descends to the quotient $\mathfrak M$. Similarly, $G_W$ acts on $E(V,W)$ by $g(B,i,j) = (B,ig^{-1},gj)$, and this also descends to $\mathfrak M$. Since they commute, these define an action of $G_W\times \mathbb G_m$, which is the action that Nakajima denotes by a "$*$". Thus
$$
(t,g)\star(B,i,j) = (t.B,tig^{-1},tgj). 
$$

The action of $\rho(\mathbb C^\times)$ is via $G_V$, whereas the action of $\lambda$ is via $G_W$. As you pointed out, the $G_W$-action  leaves $B$ invariant, hence if $\rho(t)(B,i,j) = \lambda(t)*(B,i,j)$ we must have $\rho(t)(B)=B$. But this exactly means that the map $B_h$ for an edge $h=(i\to j)$ must map $V_i^{\alpha}$, the $\alpha$-weight space of $\rho(\mathbb G_m)$ in $V_i$ into the $\alpha$-eigenspace of $\rho(\mathbb C^\times)$ in $V_j$, which yields the inclusions $(1)$ $(2)$ and $(3)$ that you quote.

Comment: I thought the action of $G_V$ was by conjugation on $B$

Comment: It is essentially -- if $h \in \mathrm{Hom}(V_i,V_j)$ then $g.h = g_j h g_i^{-1}$, hence if $h$ is fixed by the $G_V$ action, and $v \in V_i$ satisfies $g_i(v)=\lambda.v$ then $g_j(h(v)) = (g_j h g_i^{-1})(g_i(v)) = g_jhg_i^{-1}(\lambda.v) =\lambda.h(v)$.

Comment: I'm confused. the $*$ action you write makes sense when he first introduces it at the top of page 13. but in the proof of the lemma on 15, he writes $\lambda(t)*(B,i,j)$, so only one parameter acting but he still uses $*$. Is that one referring to only the $G_W$ action? It seems like an overload/abuse of notation. If that is what's happening then I think I understand everything else.

Comment: The way he writes it, Nakajima looks like he is introducing a one-parameter subgroup of $G_W$, rather than $G_W\times \mathbb G_m$, but of course $G_W$ is a subgroup of the product group, so $\lambda(t)*(B,i,j)$ is essentially (depending on whether you think suppressing inclusion maps is an abuse of notation or not) correct. I don't think he introduces separate notation for the restriction of the $*$-action to $G_W$, so I imagine that's why he sticks to using the $*$ notation, even though the action of $\lambda$ does not involved the $\mathbb G_m$ factor.